# Is it possible to avoid repetitive generic checks for free standing functions?

Tags: d

I like freestanding functions because I can call the dot product like `v1.dot(v2)` or `dot(v1,v2)` but they need more effort to write.

For example

```d
float dot(Vec)(in Vec v1, in Vec v2)
if(isVector!(Vec) && ...){
....
}
```

I also have a lot of different functions that only work in a specific dimension and the checks are all very repetitive.

It would be nice if I could write something a long the lines

```d
template(Vec)
if(isVector!Vec && ...){
   //functions here
   float dot(in Vec v1, in Vec v2){..}
   float length(in Vec v1, in Vec v2){..}
   float lengthSquared(in Vec v1, in Vec v2){..} 
}
```

I would like to call them as if every function had its own template, like `dot(v1,v2)`. Would something like this be possible or should I just stick with methods?

Comment: what about just sticking the whole `isVector!Vec && ...` part in its own template? Then you only need a single `if` condition for each free function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that I get what you're asking for. Whether you make something a method / member function is up to you and really doesn't have much to do with whether a function is templatized. If a function is expected to take a specific type, then it can just be declared to take that type whether it's a free function or a member function. And if a function is supposed to work with a variety of types, then it needs to be templatized, in which case, if one of the arguments is always supposed to be a specific type, then it can be a member function of that type, but otherwise, it has to be a free function in order to be generic.

What gets wonky is when you have a templated type, and you want to write a free function that only takes that type. You're forced to templatize the free function and test whether the type it's given is an instantiation of that type, so the template constraints start getting uglier and more complicated whereas a member function could have been clean. Instead of something like

```d
template Vector(T)
    if(...)
{
    ...
    float dot(Vector v1, Vector v2) {...}
    ...
}
```

you end up with

```d
float dot(V)(V v1, V v2)
    if(isInstanceOf!(Vector, V))
{...}
```

It's feasible, but it adds unnecessary boilerplate where the only benefit is being able to do `dot(v1, v2)` instead of `v1.dot(v2)`. I think that the vast majority of D programmers are going to think that that's just ugly and unnecessary, and they're usually going to want to do `v1.dot(v2)` anyway. UFCS is used such that almost all code is `a.foo(b)` regardless of whether `foo` is a free function or a member function. You're the first I've heard of trying to make everything `foo(a, b)` instead of `a.foo(b)`, and it won't work in the general case, because many functions are member functions and can't be called as free functions, whereas *all* functions can be called as if they were member functions - which is why generic code should favor using UFCS. It just plain makes the code work with more types and allows for types to provide specializations of free functions as member functions.

But if for whatever reason, you have templated functions that would normally be member functions that you need (or really want) to be free functions, and you want to cut down on redundant template constraints, then the way to do it is to create your own traits. e.g.

```d
template myCond(T)
{
    enum myCond = conditionAboutT1 && conditionAboutT2 && conditionAboutT3;
}
```

Then your host of functions don't have to repeat that portion of their constraints. e.g.

```d
float dot(V)(V v1, V v2)
    if(myCond!V && dotSpecificCondAboutV)
{...}

float lengthSquared(V)(V v1, V v2)
    if(myCond!V && lengthSquaredSpecificCondAboutV)
{...}
```

But trying to group a bunch of functions inside a template so that they can share a constraint is really only going to work if they're member functions. If you have something like

```d
template Vec(V)
    if(...)
{
    float dot(V v1, V v2) {...}
    float lengthSquared(V v1, V v2) {...}
}
```

then you're going to have to use the template name wherever the functions are used, and you lose out on IFTI (Implicit Function Template Instantiation), which is what makes it so that you don't have to explicitly instantiate templated functions with the types that are used with them. So, instead of getting something like

```d
auto result = dot(v1, v2);
```

or

```d
auto result = v1.dot(v2);
```

you end up with something like

```d
auto result = Vec!Vector(v1, v2);
```

for non-templated types or

```d
auto result = Vec!(Vector!float)(v1, v2);
```

for templated types.

Ultimately, you really need to either have these functions be member functions or to have them all listed individually with their own template constraints - but regardless, declaring your own traits to test for common stuff will reduce the length of your template constraints, making them both more easily understood and easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks, I still decided to go with free standing functions because it seems a bit nicer for a math library to do `dot(v1.unit, v2.unit)` or `length(v1 - v2)`, even if it adds a bit of boilerplate. But it might just be preference.